# rsExecutionNotFound error in SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a SQL Server Reporting Services 2005 installation that has worked great for a few years now, but has been giving me occasional glitches recently.

I'm using the default reporting services website instead of embedding reports into my application, which has proven a very efficient way to deploy the reports. The OS is Windows Server 2003 and the reports are being viewed on IE8 running XP.

It's not a big deal. Refreshing the browser brings the report right up each time. I guess it might be a cacheing issue. It does scare users, so it would be nice to squash this bug.

Any ideas?

### Server Error in '/Reports' Application.

Execution 'j0cnbcqzv5lxg1imzqouqxya' cannot be found (rsExecutionNotFound) 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportServerException: Execution 'j0cnbcqzv5lxg1imzqouqxya' cannot be found (rsExecutionNotFound)

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[ReportServerException: Execution 'j0cnbcqzv5lxg1imzqouqxya' cannot be found (rsExecutionNotFound)]
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.GetExecutionInfo() +289
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.SetExecutionId(String executionId, Boolean fullReportLoad) +120
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.LoadFromUrlQuery(NameValueCollection requestParameters, Boolean fullReportLoad) +101
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataOperation..ctor() +321
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.GetHandler(String operationType) +458
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +56
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +181
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3603; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3082

Answer (score 2):

Try this (extending the "report session" timeout)
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgalla/archive/2006/10/11/session-timeout-during-execution.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/0ab399df-56b3-4ac8-a703-4001e7a5fb18) that might help...not sure if you tried it already.

In this case updating Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll was a fix.

I also saw where it could be caused by a problem with NT Authority\Network Service account.

A quick "Google" with *SSRS 2005 Execution "cannot be found"* produced quite a few other options as well.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here :

http://blogs.msdn.com/jgalla/archive/2006/10/11/session-timeout-during-execution.aspx

This can happen when a report takes a long time to run, using a script with rs.exe to increase the RS session lifetime may well help.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this question in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050593/execution-iwy2vpzo52pmp555ftfn4455-cannot-be-found-rsexecutionnotfound).

It is to do with the execution context in the Session expiring.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error ocurred only in the Browsers Internet Explorer 8 and Internet Explorer 9 with reports that takes more than 20 minutes for execute.
I solved this problem optimizing the sql query procedure ( before optimize took 30 minutes to execute ) and now takes 3 minutes.

I tried to configure increasing the session timeout in ReportManager configuration but anything solve the problem.

This error is weird because in Google Chrome and Firefox works fine!

Answer (score 0):

```
the reason of this issue may be below:
1 - > your login has expired OR
2 - > The server on which SSRS report deployed, below services has stopped
    a - > MS SQL SERVER
    b - > SQL Server Agent is not running

to resolve go to the server and start these services
```

Comment: Actually, I'm running Express edition which means that the SQL Server Agent wasn't cleaning up the reporting services sessions.

My report took 10 seconds to run and 2 seconds to export.   

I'd get the error when exporting a report to excel into my app an hour after I exported the report.

Answer (score 0):

None of the aforementioned things worked for me. My reports aren't working from the Report browser interface, even though it used to. It does however work from the server URL.

eg) The `/ReportServer` context works fine, and NOT the `/Reports` context whilst browsing to reports.

This is ok since I can still upload reports, and our applications use the server URL.